# Calculating the plastic section modulus, Z, of an arc of a circle

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, structures

[image]I am trying to find a simplified formula for determining the plastic section modulus, Z, of an arc of a circle.

In my case, I have a 20" diameter 0.375" thick pipe and I am cutting a 6" diameter hole into it. Then, I am trying to check its reduced moment capacity, Fy * Z.

I tried calculating I and y to get I/y, but then realized that is the formula for the elastic section modulus, S, not plastic section modulus, Z. I researched and found that the formula for Z is AcYc + AtYt, but could not find a formula for calculating either of those values. I also have no clue how to derive them on my own - I have always resorted to reference materials for Z.

Any and all assistance would be fantastic! Thank you all!

Comment: I diagram would help. for a pipe with a cut-off hole, the Z varies depending on the location of the hole wrt the neutral axis.

Comment: My apologies, still learning how to use this site! I edited and updated to include a diagram to show how I want to cut the hole. I want the Z at the middle of the hole, where the cut is largest (6").

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the plastic modulus is that
$$
ZF_y=M_p
$$
where $M_p$ is the moment developed by the fully plastic section.

A very crude diagram of this would be
[image]

You need to find a depth $h$ such that $A(h)F_y = \bar{A}(h)F_y$, where $A(h)$ is the cross-sectional area below $h$ and $\bar{A}(h)$ is the cross-sectional area above $h$.

After you find this depth, you can simply calculate the bending moment with respect to $h$ and you'll get $M_p$. Or, if you are truly interested in $Z$, calculate that.